# Mousemove events not firing on mobile with create.js

Tags: mobile, createjs, easeljs, mousemove

For my application, I need continous updates of the user's touch/mouse position, but I can't seem to get pressmove events firing on mobile devices with easeljs-0.8.1.min.js

I've enabled Touch on the stage with

```
createjs.Touch.enable(stage, true, false);
```

and testing with

```
stage.addEventListener("pressmove", function (evt) {
    console.log("stage pressmove");
});
```

works on desktops, but gives no results on Android Chrome and iOS Chrome.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stage will not dispatch a pressmove event. That event is only fired by displayObjects that live on the stage. You can use the `stagemousemove` event instead, which is always fired, no matter what us under the mouse on the stage.

```
stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove", function (evt) {
    console.log("stagemousemove");
});
```

http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#event_stagemousemove

Comment: In my testing, the stage certainly does dispatch pressmove events, at least on Windows desktop in Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Comment: ...there's a DisplayObject filling the stage though, so the event could be bubbling from that.

On mobile however, neither stagemousemove nor pressmove fire. I'm testing with Chrome on Android, viewing the console output on desktop Chrome using chrome://inspect. Also, the event listener functions aren't being executed on mobile Chrome or Chrome / Safari on iOS.

Comment: Pressmove doesn't bubble, so listening on the stage would not redispatch the event from a child of the stage. You might be right about Stage dispatching pressmove itself though -- but it is possible that the Touch class doesn't fully support it. Feel free to open a bug on the EaselJS issue list on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - error on my end :/

This behaviour occurred when I redefined the stage in my FlashCC code like this:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
```

It turns out that both **stage** and **canvas** are already defined in the HTML output from FlashCC. Accessing the stage from FlashCC like this:

```
stage.addEventListener("stagemousemove", function (evt) {
    console.log("stagemousemove");
});
```

without the declaration gives the expected result, also on mobile.